# TFS 2010 - How to associate a bug with a Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm working in a project and I'm trying to optimize testing process so, when I execute a test case and I found a bug, I would like to associate this bug to the current build.

The builds are created automatically but when I try to select the built in the droplist there are not builds to select, so... How can I do it to get all the builds that I've made automatically?

Maybe is there any issue with Global List?

Im using VS 2010 and I have installed TFS 2010 Power Tools.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: On the System Info tab, are you saying that the Found in Build dropdown doesn't have the builds you're looking for?

Comment: That is exactly what's happen to me. Do you know any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The global list is normally updated by an event subscription on the server that handles the BuildCompleted event. On your TFS server, there should be an executable named BisSubscribe.exe. You can use that to verify or fix the subscription. For more details, check out Jason Prickett's blog post on [How to filter the Build Completion Event](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2006/09/05/how-to-filter-the-build-completion-event.aspx).

Comment: And do you know why the server did not executed this event to subscribes my builds? Thank you